# Big plugin - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

I'm about to start working on my new project. It'll be an eshop. Problem is, that I want to run it on my already created 'core cms' (containing users, user groups, acl, custom pages, upload plugin and so on). I'd like to create eshop plugin, because of hierarchical structure. But, my eshop is going to have about 50 different controllers. For example I want to create ChartsController that will be shared by 2 or 3 other eshop controllers (statictics of sale, stats of  traffic ...). It seems to be nicer as plugin for me, but (and here is the problem) I can't have plugin in plugin according to CakePHP structure. Or can I ? And is there a chance for this big plugin to slow down page loading ? Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a plugin within a plugin, but you can have a plugin that depends on another plugin. Any plugin can use other plugins that are alongside it in the same plugins folder. You have to be careful to avoid things getting messy, but it's definitely possible.

If your page is slow, then your page is slow. I don't think the fact that it's a plugin will significantly affect page speed.